# DirectInput8 EnumDevices sometimes painfully slow

Tags: c++, wait, directinput

Sometimes (in about 50% of runs), EnumDevices takes 5-10 seconds to return. Normally it is almost instant. I couldn't find any other reports of this kind of behaviour.

When things are this slow, it's ok to profile by watching stdout :) This:

```
std::cout << "A";
directInput8Interface->EnumDevices(DI8DEVCLASS_GAMECTRL, MyCallback, NULL, DIEDFL_ATTACHEDONLY);
std::cout << "C";

...

BOOL CALLBACK MyCallback(LPCDIDEVICEINSTANCE, LPVOID)
{
    std::cout << "B";
    return DIENUM_CONTINUE;
}
```

Seems to hang at a random point through enumerating devices - sometimes it'll be before the callback is called at all, sometimes after a couple, and sometimes it will be after the last call to it.

This is clearly a simplified chunk of code; I'm actually using the OIS input library ( http://sourceforge.net/projects/wgois/ ), so for context, please see the full source here:

http://wgois.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/wgois/ois/trunk/src/win32/Win32InputManager.cpp?revision=39&view=markup

There doesn't seem to be anything particularly fruity going on there though, but possibly something in their initialisation could be the cause - I don't know enough about DI8 to spot it.

Any ideas about why it could be so slow will be greatly appreciated!

EDIT:

I've managed to catch the hang in an etl trace file and analysed it in Windows Performance Analyzer. It looks like `EnumDevices` eventually calls through to `DInput8.dll!fGetProductStringFromDevice`, which calls `HIDUSB.SYS!HumCallUSB`, which calls `KeWaitForSingleObject` and waits. 9 times out of 10 (literally - there are 10 samples in the trace) this returns very quickly (324us each), with the readying callstack containing `usbport.sys!USBPORT_Core_iCompleteDoneTransfer` followed by `HIDUSB.SYS!HumCallUsbComplete`, which looks quite normal.

But 1 time in 10, this takes almost exactly 5 seconds to return. On the readying callstack is `ntkrnlmp.exe!KiTimerExpiration` instead of the `HIDUSB.SYS` function. I guess all this indicates that the HIDUSB.SYS driver is querying devices asynchronously with a timeout of 5 seconds, and sometimes it fails and hits this timeout.

I don't know whether this failure is associated with any one device in particular (I do have a few USB HIDs) or if it's random - it's hard to test because it doesn't always happen. Again, any information anyone can give me will be appreciated, though I don't hold out any hope for Microsoft fixing this any time soon given the odd situation DirectInput is in!

Perhaps I'll just have to start initialising input earlier, asynchronously, and accept that sometimes there'll be a 5 second delay before user input can happen.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I was running into this too, largely as an end user, but it's been annoying the hell out of me for years. I didn't realize it was this issue until I ran into it on an open source project and was able to debug it.

Turns out it was my USB Headphone DAC (The Objective DAC from Massdrop), it installs the driver: `wdma_usb.inf_amd64_134cb113911feba4\wdma_usb.inf` for Device Instance ID `USB\VID_262A&PID_1048&MI_01\7&F217D4F&0&0001` and then shows up in Device Manager under Sound, video and game controllers as: `ODAC-revB USB DAC` and, under Human Interface Devices as: `USB Input Device` and `HID-compliant consumer control device`.

I have no idea what the HID entries do but... When they are enabled and this DAC is set as the Audio Output device both IDirectInput8_CreateDevice and EnumDevices are painfully slow. Disabling the "USB Input Device" entry seems to cause no negative effects and completely solves my issue.

Changing the Audio output from the DAC to anything else also weirdly solved the issue.

This was so bad that it made the Gamepad Configuration dialog joy.cpl unusable, hanging and eventually crashing.

I was wanting this to just be a comment but I don't have enough rep for it, and this is pretty much the only place on the internet that describes this problem though so hopefully this helps someone else one day!

Comment: Very interesting! Thanks! I never did get to the bottom of this and never had it happen on any other machine, so I assumed it's badly-behaving devices or something, and your report suggests the same! It's good to know I'm not the only one it affects!

Comment: An update: Sometimes it would install a different wdma_usb.inf driver, which would also have the same issue.

This issue no longer occurs on my new PC though. The old one was an Intel Haswell machine.

Comment: You're a savior. I had this problem for almost 10 years. Disabled several obscure "USB Input Device" entries and the problem is gone, 10 secs down to 200 ms. Though I'll add all those devices showed "input.inf"; none had anything with "wdma". I also had an Objective DAC (before it broke) but not from Massdrop. I think JDS Labs sells some newer revision of them now which supposedly breaks less often: https://blog.jdslabs.com/2015/05/releasing-odac-revb/ I'll try throwing this at them, maybe we'll learn something interesting.

Comment: Some additional reading, just so we can get all of this info linking back to eachother:

https://github.com/godotengine/godot/issues/20566

https://github.com/pygame/pygame/issues/2173

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue. I have a Corsair K65 LUX RGB keyboard. I updated CUE and it seems to have fixed the issue

Answer (score 1):

Got same issue when having my Corsair K55 Keyboard. Changing the keyboard of USB port fixes the issue for a while, but then it comes back later on. So it seems to be a buggy drivers issue.

Comment: Interesting, I'm experiencing the same issue and currently have Corsair K66 keyboard.

Answer (score 1):

As [DaFox has pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40449680/593146), a likely cause appears to be certain device drivers being enabled. I contacted [JDS Labs](https://jdslabs.com/) support (who sell one device which happens to install one such driver) and they kindly pointed out that the root cause is actually a bug within Windows (not the installed driver), and they actually provide the solution [on their troubleshooting page](https://jdslabs.com/support/troubleshooting/). See `Games hang or experience loading delays`, which explicitly mentions `VID_262`. Disabling this driver fixes the issue without apparent side effects (under the condition that that is the only driver triggering the bug). As for what exactly is going wrong within Windows, here there be dragons.

So I guess the go-to solution (for users) is to scrape all the troubleshooting and FAQ pages for all devices which you have ever connected to your system and see if there is a mention of delays/lag caused by a driver.

As a software developer, you will probably want to benchmark the execution time of the affected code and kindly tell the user there is something wrong with their system configuration and where to look for how to fix it in case it is unreasonably long.

Answer (score 0):

Same issue with Corsair K70 Keyboard.
Quickly reconnecting keyboard fixes this, until next time. Usually happens after some DirectInput devices removed from the system or go to sleep.

Answer (score 0):

This has been plaguing me as a developer and my friend as a user for years. All games using DInput, SDL `SDL_INIT_JOYSTICK` or anything depending on that, took extremely long to initialize.

It was caused by a faulty driver of a DAC, and as pointed out by DaFox, disabling the corresponding USB Input Device resolved the issue. Although it's labeled with a different manufacturer name, the vendor IDs match.

The hardware ID of the device is `USB\VID_262A&PID_9023&REV_0001&MI_00`.

Answer (score 0):

Same issue appears to happen with a Steelseries Apex 7 keyboard. Unplugging and plugging that keyboard back again got rid of 3 freezes (of 10 seconds each) while enumerating USB devices.