# GLFW takes 30 seconds to initialize

Tags: c++, visual-studio, performance, glfw

I've been trying to get into C++ and OpenGL development and such, but I've run into an issue I can't seem to figure out with the following code:

```
int main() {
std::cout << "Attempting to load" << std::endl;

if (!glfwInit()) {
    std::cout << "Error loading GLFW" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
else {
    std::cout << "Loaded GLFW" << std::endl;
}

using namespace kreezyEngine;
using namespace graphics;

Window window("Kreezy Engine", 800, 600);

while (!window.isClosed()) {
    window.update();
}

return 0;
```

}

Now, the code works fine, it's just that I noticed it took 30 seconds to even create the window. After some debugging, I noticed that "Attempting to load" is being printed, but it takes around 30 seconds for "Loaded GLFW" to be printed in the console. I feel like thats really slow to initialize glfw, as the tutorial im watching takes no more than a second.

Any help?

Thanks :)

Comment: Are you running it in the debugger? It may be downloading or loading symbols.

Comment: Yes, but the tutorial im following also uses the debugger. So shouldnt be a difference :P

Comment: Oh no I'm not an expert at all :O Thanks tho

Comment: any updates? thanks

Comment: I have the same issue, and I am not using a debugger. I also have the GLFW error callback setup. There are no error messages. It started in less than second yesterday. Takes 30 seconds today.

Comment: I am having the same issue.

Comment: This is caused by a faulty device driver. See https://github.com/glfw/glfw/issues/1049 and consequentially https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10967795/directinput8-enumdevices-sometimes-painfully-slow